# Finding parametrisation of a curve using Newtons algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am currently reading the book *Singular Points of Plane Curves* by C.T.C. Wall.

I am stuck with exercise 2.6.2 stated as follows: "For the curve given by $y^3-9x^3y-x^4=0$, find a paramatrisation of the form $x=t^3, y=\psi(t)$, and obtain the first four non-vanishing coefficients in $\psi$."

So far I did the following (mimicking the proof of theorem 2.1.1 of the book mentioned above):

-I drew the Newton polygon and found that the line through $(4,0)$ and $(0,3)$ is its only edge.

-I did the substitution $x=x_1^3$ and $y=x_1^4(1+y_1)$ to obtain the equation
$x_1^{12}(y_1^3+3y_1^2+3y_1-9x_1y_1-9x_1)=0$.

I wanted to continue the induction process on $y_1^3+3y_1^2+3y_1-9x_1y_1-9x_1=0$ by setting $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=x_2(3+y_2)$. However this seems to lead nowhere.

Does someone know how to continue?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: difficult to give help not having that book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will find the first four non-vanishing coefficients in $\psi$. I used Wolfram Alpha to help with the substitutions; please let me know if there are any mistakes.

**Step 1.** We start with the curve
$$f(x,y) = y^3 - 9x^3y - x^4 = 0,$$
which has Newton polygon

$\hskip2in$[image: Newton Polygon 1]

Thus, we consider
$$f_\Delta(x,y) = y^3 - x^4 = 0,$$
which can be parametrized by $x = x_1^3$, $y = x_1^4$. We therefore substitute
$$x = x_1^3, \qquad y = x_1^4(1+y_1)$$
into $f(x,y)$ to obtain
$$f_1(x_1,y_1) = x_1^{12}(-9 x_1 y_1 - 9 x_1 + y_1^3 + 3 y_1^2 + 3 y_1) = 0.$$
**Step 2.** We now consider
$$f_1'(x_1,y_1) = -9 x_1 y_1 - 9 x_1 + y_1^3 + 3 y_1^2 + 3 y_1 = 0,$$
which has Newton polygon

$\hskip2.75in$[image: Newton Polygon 2]

Thus, we consider
$$f_{1\Delta}(x_1,y_1) = -9x_1 +3y_1 = 0,$$
which can be parametrized by $x_1 = x_2$, $y_1 = 3x_2$. We therefore substitute
$$x_1 = x_2, \qquad y_1 = x_2(3+y_2)$$
into $f_1(x_1,y_1)$ to obtain
$$f_2(x_2,y_2) = x_2^{13}(x_2^{2} y_2^3 + 9 x_2^{2} y_2^2 + 27 x_2^{2} y_2 + 27
x_2^{2} + 3 x_2 y_2^2 + 9 x_2 y_2 + 3 y_2) = 0.$$
**Step 3.** We now consider
$$f_2'(x_2,y_2) = x_2^{2} y_2^3 + 9 x_2^{2} y_2^2 + 27 x_2^{2} y_2 + 27
x_2^{2} + 3 x_2 y_2^2 + 9 x_2 y_2 + 3 y_2 = 0,$$
which has Newton polygon

$\hskip2.5in$[image: Newton Polygon 3]

Thus, we consider
$$f_{2\Delta}(x_2,y_2) = 27x_2^2 + 3y_2 = 0,$$
which can be parametrized by $x_2 = x_3$, $y_2 = -9x_3^2$. We therefore
substitute
$$x_2 = x_3, \qquad y_2 = x_3^2(-9+y_3)$$
into $f_2(x_2,y_2)$ to obtain
$$f_3(x_3,y_3) = x_3^{15}\left(
  \begin{aligned}
    x_3^{6} y_3^3 - 27 x_3^{6} y_3^2 + 243 x_3^{6} y_3 - 729 x_3^{6} + 9
    x_3^{4} y_3^2 - 162 x_3^{4} y_3 + 729 x_3^{4} + 3 x_3^{3} y_3^2\\ - 54
    x_3^{3} y_3 + 243 x_3^{3} + 27 x_3^{2} y_3 - 243 x_3^{2} + 9 x_3 y_3 -
    81 x_3 + 3 y_3
  \end{aligned}
\right) = 0.$$

**Step 4.** We now consider
$$f_3'(x_3,y_3) = \left(
  \begin{aligned}
    x_3^{6} y_3^3 - 27 x_3^{6} y_3^2 + 243 x_3^{6} y_3 - 729 x_3^{6} + 9
    x_3^{4} y_3^2 - 162 x_3^{4} y_3 + 729 x_3^{4} + 3 x_3^{3} y_3^2\\ - 54
    x_3^{3} y_3 + 243 x_3^{3} + 27 x_3^{2} y_3 - 243 x_3^{2} + 9 x_3 y_3 -
    81 x_3 + 3 y_3
  \end{aligned}
\right) = 0,$$
which has Newton polygon

$\hskip1.375in$[image: Newton Polygon 4]

Thus, we consider
$$f_{3\Delta}(x_3,y_3) = -81x_3 + 3y_3 = 0,$$
which can be parametrized by $x_3 = x_4$, $y_3 = 27x_4$. We therefore substitute
$$x_3 = x_4, \qquad y_3 = x_4(27+y_4)$$
into $f_3(x_3,y_3)$.

**Conclusion.** Now we combine all of our substitutions to obtain
\begin{align*}
  x &= x_1^3 & y &= x_1^4(1+y_1)\\
  x &= x_2^3 & y &= x_2^4\bigl(1+x_2(3+y_2)\bigr)\\
  x &= x_3^3 & y &= x_3^4\bigl(1+x_3\bigl(3+x_3^2(-9+y_3)\bigr)\bigr)\\
  x &= x_4^3 & y &= x_4^4\bigl(1+x_4\bigl(3+x_4^2\bigl(-9+x_4(27+y_4)\bigr)\bigr)\bigr)\\
  &~~~\!\!\vdots  & &~~~\!\!\vdots\\
  x &= t^3   & y &= t^4 + 3t^5 - 9 t^7 + 27t^8 + \cdots \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Hello i do not really know about this topic, but i could help with the parametrization.
Here 
y³ - 9x³y - x⁴ =0
then 
3y²dy/dx - 9x³ dy/dx -27x²y - 4x³ =0
so that
dy/dx = (4x³ - 27x²y)/(3y² - 9x³)
WE have
dy/dt = 4x³ - 27x²y
 dx/dt =3y² - 9x³

x=t³   => dx/dt =3t²
 3t²=3y² - 9x³

y=t√(t² +3t^4)
hence
 y = ∫ 4t^9dt  - 27∫t^7√(1+3t^4) dt

AM sure you could do the integration.